# How to destructure es6 javascript nested objects

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, destructuring

I want to structure object  in es6 but not getting results.

```
let animal ={
      data:{
          typee:{
              title: "Cow",
              legs:4
          }
      }
} 

let {data:{typee:{title,legs}}}=animal;
```

now `console.log(data)` giving output `Error: data is not defined`.
What I am doing wrong ?

Comment: If you want that, why not just `let { data } = animal;`?

Comment: It's not clear what variables you want to end up with. Do you want `title` and `legs`, `data` and `typee`, or all four?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When destructuring nested objects, the interim values are not assigned to consts/variables. You'll have to assign them explictly:

```js
const animal = {"data":{"typee":{"title":"Cow","legs":4}}};

const {
  data, // assign the data
  data: {
    typee, // assign the typee
    typee: {
      title,
      legs
    }
  }
} = animal;

console.log(data, typee, title, legs);
```

Comment: @ Ashwani - You only need the `data,` and `typee,` parts of that if you want those variables (as suggested by your `console.log(data)` statement). If you *just* want `title` and `legs`, just leave `data,` and `typee,` out.

Comment: Heh, I actually meant the opposite. :-) If they *only* want `title` and `legs`, they can just use `{data: {typee: {title, legs } } }`. I was basically thinking it was the `console.log` that was wrong in the question, they did it just for debugging or something, rather than the destructuring. Anyway, good answer, tells them what was going on and, if they want `data` and `typee`, how to get them.

Answer (score 0):

```
let {data:{typee:{title,legs}}}=animal;
```

Creates `title` and `legs` not `data`. If you want to get one of the other encapsulating properties as well you have to specify it separately:

```
//creates data along with title and legs
let {data, data:{typee:{title,legs}}}=animal;
console.log(data,title,legs);
```